# Nested IF to Calculate Complete or Incomplete

Tags: 2010, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have several columns on a list that are radio buttons for either "Completed" or "Not Applicable". I need to draw the status of an item based on if those columns have data in them. Someone may choose either option on the radio button, but if all columns have data in them, then I need to have the status set as Complete. I have tried nested IF and ISBLANK formulas and I'm not having much luck. I have this formula working, but it doesn't throw the Complete or Incomplete status, it just gives me Yes or No:

```
=IF(
   AND(
       ISBLANK([COL1])=""
      )
  ,IF(
      AND(
          ISBLANK([COL2])=""
         )
      ,"Complete"
      ,"Incomplete"
     )
  )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I reformatted your formula, You are basically doing ``TRUE=""`` and ``FALSE=""``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this, I tested with 2 columns it is working fine

```
=IF(ISBLANK(Title),"InComplete",IF(ISBLANK(Url),"Incomplete","Complete"))
```

Idea is to use check with another column when first condition is not met, like in above when Title column is blank it will display incomplete but if Title has value it will go and check for Url column, if it is blank it will assign Incomplete and it has value it will assign Complete, similar way you can put another condition for another column by replacing "Complete" with another IF condition... so ideally there would be only one "Complete" value which would in the end...

Hope this helps..

Comment: You are an absolute genius! Thank you so much... this worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
=IF(
    AND(
        NOT(ISBLANK([Col1]))
        ,NOT(ISBLANK([Col2]))
       )
   ,"Complete"
   , ... other tests here
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

=IF(ISBLANK(Col1),"Incomplete","Completed")

Comment: That works for one column, but I need to make it work for multiple columns! That's where I'm getting hung up at! Thank you :)